# IE не понимает метод forEach

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Использую маленький скрипт

```
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

 function transition() {
  if (this.classList.contains('active-card')) {
  this.classList.remove('active-card');
 } else {
  this.classList.add('active-card');
 }
 }

 cards.forEach(function (card) {return card.addEventListener('click', transition);});
```

Работает везде, кроме браузера IE, который ругается на метод forEach. Как это исправить? Читала, что можно написать полифилл, но не поняла, как его писать.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в самом методе [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), который вполне присутствует в IE.

А в методе [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), который описан в коллекции, которую возвращает [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Как раз этот метод реализован еще не во всех браузерах.

Вместо него можно использовать обычный `forEach`, например так:

```
[].forEach.call(cards, function (card) {return card.addEventListener('click', transition);});
```

Comment: да, именно так! Прошу прощение за не точное описание проблемы. Но вариант с обычным forEach мне тоже не помогает. Эффект на IE не срабатывает. Может я не замечаю еще какую-то проблему..

Comment: @Alla, если клик срабатывает - значит проблема в том, какой конкретно эффект ты хочешь сделать. Возможно именно он не поддерживается.

Comment: в IE никакой реакции не выдает, кажется по прежнему не срабатывает js

Comment: @Alla, Добавь `alert` в обработчик клика, вместо твоего `if`. В какой версии IE идет проверка? Есть ли ошибки в консоли?

Comment: пишет "Не удалось получить свойство "call" ссылки, значение которой не определено или является NULL", версия IE 11

Comment: @Alla, значит твой код отличается от примера, приведенного в ответе, либо версия IE Не 11, либо включен какой-нибудь режим совместимости.