# Как переписать скрипт с forEach на обычный for

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let scrollDistance = window.scrollY;

        document.querySelectorAll('.block').forEach((el, i) => {
            if (el.offsetTop - document.querySelector('.header').clientHeight <= scrollDistance) {
                document.querySelectorAll('.menu__body a').forEach((el) => {
                    if (el.classList.contains('_active')) {
                        el.classList.remove('_active');
                    }
                    console.log(el)
                });
                document.querySelectorAll('.menu__body li')[i].querySelector('a').classList.add('_active');
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: 1 вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Что значит "как"? Вы не знаете, как пишется обычный цикл `for`?

Comment: IE не дружит с таким вариантом. Полифилы не помогают.

Comment: IE ещё ктото требует поддерживать?

Comment: Как пишется знаю. с 11 строкой не понятно а конкретно как переписать это [i]

Comment: ну не совсем IE точнее IE11 не воспринимает forEach

Comment: @eri: в последнее время, зачастую, это инициатива самого исполнителя ;-)

Comment: @СлаваГрачев "Как пишется знаю. с 11 строкой не понятно а конкретно как переписать это [i]" --- а что, в `for` отменили счётчики?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [IE не понимает метод forEach](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/905511/ie-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-foreach)

Comment: @eri, если речь идёт о госучреждении, то порой ещё как. По крайней мере 9, 10 и 11 версий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы обратил ваше внимание на то, что на каждый триггер скролла - вы дёргаете DOM.
Это те же `.block`, `.header.`, `.menu__body a`, `.menu__body li`, не лучше ли их вынести один раз за пределы слушателя, чтобы снизить операции с DOM ?

Вот переписанный вариант:

```js
const collection = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__body a');
const header = document.querySelector('.header');

let scrollDistance = window.scrollY;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  scrollDistance = window.scrollY;

  for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    const el = collection[i];

    if (el.offsetTop - header.clientHeight <= scrollDistance) {
      for (let j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
        if (el.classList.contains('_active')) {
          el.classList.remove('_active');
        }
      }

      links[i].classList.add('_active');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: спасибо только немного добавил ибо класс _active только добавлялся const $el = links[j];
    if ($el.classList.contains('_active')) {
     $el.classList.remove('_active');
    }

Comment: Не пойму в чем дело этот вариант тоже не хочет работать в IE11

Comment: попробуйте в for переменные через var указать @СлаваГрачев

Comment: я использую сборку Gulp с babel и он все это делает но скрипт не хочет работать и ошибок никаких

Answer (score 1):

Технически, никак, это разные алгоритмы, for - цикл,  forEach  как таковым им и не является. Теперь как переписать?

```js
const names = ['Дима', 'Паша', 'Петя']; 
//ForEach - Метод и ему подобные принимают аргумент, который является на итерации его - текущим. 
names.forEach((current, index) => console.log(current, index));  

//For - предоставляет собственный счетчик и не является функцией/методом. 
for (let i = 0; i<names.length; i++) { 
  //Тут для ясности текущий запишем сразу в переменную 
  const current = names[i]; 
  console.log(current);
}
  
//Буква I В [???] - спооб получить элемент по его индексу.  
const str = 'Дима я сейчас возьму последнюю букву, знаешь как:?'; 
const last = str[str.length - 1]; 
console.log(last); //Последний символ знак вопроса.
```

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menu__body li')[i].querySelector('a').classList.add('_active');
```

Тут ошибки не вижу.

Comment: дело не в ошибке а в том что не понимаю как это переписать с обычным for

Comment: В таком случае мне не понятно, что именно вам не понятно. Вы умеете пользоваться  for, тем более выше пример и в интернете примеров с for  полно.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Разобрался